# How can we create our own CDN links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cdn

Suppose we have two files: style.css and stylejs.js.

Is there a way we can create a CDN link for our files so that others can use it by linking the CDN link just like we do for bootstrap and angular?

If yes, can someone tell me how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a CDN of your own, or how to use the services of a CDN? Either way, ServerFault.com would be a better place to ask, as this isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Barmar Yep both. Guess I posted in the wrong site. However, I got the answer. Thanks for the guidance. I will make sure to use that portal the next time I have a clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are already using those files on your own website you can easily give links to those files like `http://www.yoursite.com/path/to/your/file/style.js`.

If you want to continue serving different versions you can achieve that by adding version numbers to your files like `style.1.2.3.js` or keeping them in separate directories like `/v1.2/style.js`.

The other option is to use some sort of CDN Hosting service like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com). You can find more services like this with a quick google search.

Comment: The first option doesn't make it a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Just put these files on any host with clear URL, something like cdn.myhost.com/style.css
cdn.myhost.com/js.js

then anyone can link them to their code.

Comment: Do you know what a CDN is? Naming a host "cdn" doesn't make it a CDN.

Comment: @Barmar isn't it to make higher availability and higher response time through choosing the correct server regarding your location?
But he didn't ask for the definition of the CDN and from the way he asked the question its obvious that just a subdomain or just telling that the files can be served staticly will work.

Comment: Yes, that's what a CDN is. I assumed that he was looking for a way to make his files highly available, similar to the way jQuery and Bootstrap code is. You don't have to do anything special just to make them accessible with a URL.

Comment: What you said is 100% correct about the speed stuff, but on the other hand i assumed that's not what he was looking for, if you are trying to do this i don't think that this is the way you are going to ask about it. If you want to rebuild linux kernel as example you wouldnt ask where do i start at! Thats my assumption