# How to generate script tag with CDN link for users to copy and paste and embed content? React + Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a React and Node app. What I want to do is when the user selects embed, a link is generated and HTML is available to copy and paste. For example -

```
<div user-id="12"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.name.com/name.v1.js" async="async"></script>
```

How do I generate this CDN link from my build? and then tie an id to it?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC many CDNs have deterministic URLs based in the GitHub/npm URL

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919189/how-can-we-create-our-own-cdn-links

Comment: check this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your public folder, generate a new html file over there like `mynewpage.html`. Place all of the required content like images, stylesheets everything in public folder.

Then when user hit on embed get page content using whether axios or others and render the content in `pre` tags.